# Type more than one letter at a time with pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm using pyautogui to input a string into an input box but both `write` and `typewrite` types one letter at a time.

```
filename = 'example.html'
pyautogui.write(filename)
```

Is there a way to just input the whole string in one go instead?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the interval parameter:

```
# type with quarter-second pause in between each key
pyautogui.write('Hello world!', interval=0.25)
```

Comment: It looks like "write" is actually just "typewrite" with the interval set to 0. I just checked and didn't know that before. Haha seems there isn't a way to do it yet with typewrite. Maybe I can just do a copy and paste with pyautogui? Although I'm not sure how this would work if I'm using it to scrape a website.


From the library:
write = typewrite 
def typewrite(message, interval=0.0, logScreenshot=None, _pause=True):

Comment: You could iterate over the string and write every letter, but, selenium wouldn't be a better option to scrape a website?

Comment: Oh my bad, I didn't explain this in the question. I'm using selenium to open the browser but I want to save the entire webpage, including all the CSS and JS so that when I open the saved file, it includes all the styling. I'm using pyautogui to simulate me pressing "ctrl+s", entering in the file name, and pressing enter to save.

Answer (score 0):

`pyautogui` is pretty much just emulating keystrokes, so I don't think there is a way to enter all the keystrokes at once-- they have to be sequential.

However it may work to use another library called `pyperclip` (incidentally from the same author who wrote pyautogui) to paste your text into the input box. It would work something like this:

```
import pyperclip
# copy the text to the clipboard
pyperclip.copy('example.html')
# use pyautogui to select the input box you want
pyautogui.click(x, y)
# use pyperclip to paste
pyperclip.paste()
```

Comment: This raises an attribute error on Mac: AttributeError: NSStringPboardType

The only help I could find on this is from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68595572/pyperclip-1-8-2-conflicting-with-pyautogui. It seems like this just won't work if something imports both pyautogui and pyperclip?

Comment: Damn, looks like this is still an open issue on its github: https://github.com/asweigart/pyperclip/issues/208